# Octagon Windows - are they worth replacing?

Tags: windows, replacement

Intro:
My husband and I bought an older home that never actually got finished (no interior casing on windows, no door frames/fixtures, plywood floors throughout...). As far as we know, the foundation was poured in the late 70's and the remainder of what was built happened between the mid 80s-90s.

Although there are many interesting quirks to what the original owner started, he invested higher quality materials for certain things, like Anderson windows (crank-outs, sadly). He also installed 2 octagon-stained windows, which I thought were a little outdated at first, but they do reflect beautiful light when the sun hits and I think could be really nice if we found the right, updated replacements. They are both placed high on the walls (12-15ft from the ground), close to the top of the ceiling. One is in the downstairs bathroom, the other is in the kitchen (the are on opposite sides of the house in mirroring positions).

**The real question** 
I'm wondering anyone has advice on replacing octagon windows and if it would be worth investing in having brand new ones replaced by a professional or if it something worth pursuing ourselves. We live in New England where we get hot/humid summers and cold/snowy winters... Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Honestly, I would say "ask a Realtor" or market assessor who will have an idea about market values. You need to know which house characteristics make people fall in love with the house, vs. which are useless kitsch that's expensive to maintain.

Comment: Worth it for what reason? What's your particular concern? With no reason, no, it's not worth it. Are the octagon windows also casements, or stationary? Is there any indication that they're leaky?

Comment: post pictures please

Comment: Unfortunately, any answer to this question will be a matter of opinion. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.